# How do I make 'import x' return a subclass of types.ModuleType?

Tags: python

Can Python's `import` statement return a subclass of `types.ModuleType` using import hooks? I would like to override `__getattribute__` to display a runtime warning when code outside a certain module reference names that aren't in `__all__`.

I know how to replace `sys.modules['foo']` after it's been imported. What I want is to instrument modules that match a pattern *as they are imported* so the importing code has an opportunity to trigger the warning.

Python frowns on the idea of making things public and private. This idea isn't about preventing your module's users from typing `from somemodule import sys`; instead, it is a documentation tool. This kind of instrumentation should make it much easier to document your module's API by including a correct  `__all__`. It should help you avoid accidentally referencing `sys` as `somemodule.sys` instead of simply `import sys`.

Answer (score 5):

Since I missed the point of your question before you edited it, I thought I'd take another whack (while leaving my original answer for posterity).

Here's an alternative that also doesn't need the import hook. It can easily be used on a module-by-module basis: a module that includes this code will have the special `__getattribute__()` behavior, while other modules will behave as usual.

```
class StrictModule(types.ModuleType):

    def __getattribute__(self, key):
        if key is "__dict__":  # fake __dict__ with only visible attributes
            return dict((k, v) for k, v in globals().iteritems()
                        if k.startswith("__") or k in __all__)
        if (key.startswith("__") or key in __all__) and key in globals():
            return globals()[key]
        else:
            raise AttributeError("'module' object has no attribute '%s'"  % key)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        globals()[key] = value

sys.modules[__name__] = StrictModule(__name__)
```

Keep in mind this "restriction" is easy to get around by simply calling the regular `module` type's `__getattribute__()` (or for that matter, the `object` type's). I get the impression that you are trying to provide some kind of "private member" restriction for your modules. There's almost never any point to this.

Comment: The point is really that perhaps it would be better if more Python modules had a correct `__all__`, as the list of names the author thinks you need to use the module. You might want this if you are trying to find your way around complicated Python modules that import many other modules to do their work by using dir() and IPython tab completion.

Comment: I tend to just use a leading underscore for something I don't think the user of my module should need access to.

Comment: Do you consistently `import sys as _sys`?

Comment: Nah, but `help()` doesn't show modules even without `__all__`, so there isn't any need to.

Answer (score 3):

You don't even need an import hook. Simply put a reference to the object in Python's module registry `sys.modules` under the desired name, and any future `import` statement in the Python session (even in other modules) will import a reference to that entity.

```
import types, sys

class MyModuleType(types.ModuleType):
    pass

sys.modules["foo"] = MyModuleType("foo")

import foo

print type(foo)   # MyModuleType
```

Python does not even care whether the objects in `sys.modules` are actually modules or some other type of object entirely. You could chuck an `int` in there and not a single f*** would be given.

```
sys.modules["answer"] = 42
import answer
```

Comment: Not the question! I know how to do this but it's awkward to wrap modules after the fact, perhaps after the 'api violation' warning would have been given by the importing module. What I want to do is enable this warning for every module that matches a pattern as it's imported, putting the names inside the module subclass instead of wrapping and replacing a module.

Comment: I think you could have a module do something similar for itself as it's imported. In other words, a module could import itself *as* a subclass of the standard module type. Would this solve your problem, or do you want to have it happen for e.g. a special file extension?

Answer (score 3):

You could adapt [this ActiveState recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577689-enforce-__all__-outside-the-import-antipattern/), perhaps something like this:

```
# safemodule.py
import sys
import types
import warnings

class EncapsulationWarning(RuntimeWarning): pass

class ModuleWrapper(types.ModuleType):
    def __init__(self, context):
        self.context = context
        super(ModuleWrapper, self).__init__(
                context.__name__,
                context.__doc__)

    def __getattribute__(self, key):
        context = object.__getattribute__(self, 'context')
        if hasattr(context, '__all__') and key not in context.__all__:
            warnings.warn('%s not in %s.__all__' % (key, context.__name__),
                          EncapsulationWarning,
                          2)
        return context.__getattribute__(key)

if 'old_import' not in globals():
    old_import = __import__

    def safe_import(*args, **kwargs):
        m = old_import(*args, **kwargs)
        return ModuleWrapper(m)

    __builtins__['__import__'] = safe_import
```

Then, use it like this:

```
C:\temp>python
ActivePython 2.5.2.2 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Mar 27 2008, 17:57:18) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import safemodule
>>> import sys
>>> type(sys)
<class 'safemodule.ModuleWrapper'>
>>>
```

You can, of course, adapt this to wrap certain modules only, etc.